# Python - Replacing a function in the socket library, called by another library, which is called by another library

Tags: python, python-3.x, monkeypatching

I am writing a program that needs to redefine how socket.getaddrinfo() works. I use a third party library, which imports several other items, which eventually imports httplib2, which then imports socket.

From what I've read, monkey patching is the way to override this method, but I am obviously not doing it right.

I've tried this my making the function my_getaddrinfo .  Right now it just uses the default code

```
def my_getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
addrlist = []

for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),_intenum_converter(socktype, SocketKind),proto, canonname, sa))

return addrlist

import socket
socket.getaddrinfo = my_getaddrinfo

#Third party library I'm trying to use
from Otherlibrary.test import testconnector
connector = testconnector(initvalue)
connector.do()
```

What ends up happening is that I get the error "name _socket not defined".  I'm sort of lost here. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: If you wish to use the original function, you need to save its reference before you monkey patch something into its place. It's unclear from the snippet you provide why you expect `_socket` to be some magic reference to the original module.

Comment: @NPE OP just copied the original source code, in which `_socket` is an internal module implemented in C that `socket` wraps.

Comment: @AlexHall: Where are you importing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `def my_getaddrinfo`, before use `_socket` you can do `from socket import _socket` and that should do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely at the source code for `socket` to see where `_socket` comes from - you need to `import _socket`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I gave credit to the person to answer first.

I figured I'd post the working code. Here is the edited function from above.

```
def my_getaddrinfo(host, port, family=0, type=0, proto=0, flags=0):
    addrlist = []

    from socket import _socket
    from socket import _intenum_converter
    from socket import AddressFamily
    from socket import SocketKind

    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        addrlist.append((_intenum_converter(af, AddressFamily),_intenum_converter(socktype, SocketKind),proto, canonname, sa))

    return addrlist
```